# Using Glass Pane with Menus

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

The documentation for Glass Panes includes example code with this comment.

```
//we're not in the content pane
//Could have special code to handle mouse events over
//the menu bar or non-system window decorations, such as
//the ones provided by the Java look and feel.
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Can someone please explain how to do that?

I've implemented a glass pane that lets users draw over my application. I want shift clicking to draw and all the normal clicks to be handled normally. I am trying to redispatch to my components, but it won't process menu clicks or drag events on my main window.

Thanks

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;

public class GlassPane extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getFormatterLogger (this.getClass ());
    private final JPanel content;
    private final List<List<Point>> shapes = new ArrayList<> ();
    private List<Point> shape = new ArrayList<> ();

    public GlassPane (JPanel content)
    {
        this.content = content;
        final Color backColor = new Color (0, 0, 0, 0);
        setBackground (backColor);
        setOpaque (false);
        addMouseListener (this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        final int width = getWidth ();
        final int height = getHeight ();
        g.setColor (getBackground ());
        g.fillRect (0, 0, width, height);
        if (!shapes.isEmpty ())
        {
            g.setColor (Color.red);
            final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            final BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke (5.0f);
            g2d.setStroke (stroke);
            for (final List<Point> s : shapes)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < s.size (); i++)
                {
                    final Point p1 = s.get (i - 1);
                    final Point p2 = s.get (i);
                    g.drawLine (p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearShapes ()
    {
        shapes.clear ();
        repaint ();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (!redispatchMouseEvent (e))
        {
            shape = new ArrayList<> ();
            shapes.add (shape);
            addMouseMotionListener (this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (!redispatchMouseEvent (e))
        {
            removeMouseMotionListener (this);
            final Iterator<List<Point>> i = shapes.iterator ();
            while (i.hasNext ())
            {
                final List<Point> shape = i.next ();
                if (shape.isEmpty ())
                {
                    i.remove ();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent (e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent (e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent (e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (!redispatchMouseEvent (e))
        {
            shape.add (e.getPoint ());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent (e);
    }

    private boolean redispatchMouseEvent (MouseEvent e)
    {
        final Point glassPanePoint = e.getPoint ();
        final Point containerPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint (this, glassPanePoint, content);

        // if (containerPoint.y < 0)
        // {
        // // we're not in the content pane
        // // Could have special code to handle mouse events over
        // // the menu bar or non-system window decorations, such as
        // // the ones provided by the Java look and feel.
        // return true;
        // }
        // else
        if (!e.isShiftDown ())
        {
            // The mouse event is probably over the content pane.
            // Find out exactly which component it's over.
            final Component component = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt (content, containerPoint.x, containerPoint.y);
            if (component != null)
            {
                logger.info ("Redispatch %s to %s", e, component);

                // Forward events over the check box.
                final Point componentPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint (this, glassPanePoint, component);
                component.dispatchEvent (new MouseEvent (component,
                                                         e.getID (),
                                                         e.getWhen (),
                                                         e.getModifiers (),
                                                         componentPoint.x,
                                                         componentPoint.y,
                                                         e.getClickCount (),
                                                         e.isPopupTrigger ()));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```